# How do I get my php to display on the browser?

Tags: php, html

How do I get my PHP to display on the browser? Currently, nothing is showing and I am not sure what is wrong?

```
<body>
testing

<?php
    echo "Hie there";
    print "Hello there";

?>

</body>
```

I expect it to display the echo but currently, nothing shows when I run it. Can you show me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Did you configure your server correctly?

Comment: I am just running the file from internet explorer, named it test.html

Comment: You have to change the file extension from `.html` to `.php`. So rename it to `test.php` and also use that in the browser.

Comment: First, you must run configured server, and then call .php file from your browser.

Comment: Tried changing it to .php just showed me the code again.

Comment: I don't know what configured server is also, running it just show nothing in html and code in php

Comment: Well, then it is likely that PHP is not installed on your server. Find out how you can install it. That depends on your server type.

Comment: use XAMPP on your pc. It will install and run a local server on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

Files like .php must have a web-server to run them. Double clicking the html file won't do it. Try installing wamp or xampp or maybe host the file on a server somewhere and open the page again.

Answer (score -1):

Php (php hypertext processor) unlike html, you will need a web server to run your scripts you can try [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html), and also you 'll have to save your php file as anything.php try and check [W3schools php tutorial](https://w3schools.com/php)

Answer (score -1):

Ok so if you are runngin on a VPS login as root

and then Create a file named install with `touch install` and then run `apt-get install nano` and then you run this `nano install` and put this code here in it and press ctrl + x and y + enter

```html
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "This script will install all esseintials for php 7.3 for you"
sleep 3

apt update
apt upgrade -y
apt install ca-certificates apt-transport-https lsb-release curl nano unzip -y
wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -O- | apt-key add -
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
apt update
apt install apache2 -y
apt install php7.3 php7.3-cli php7.3-curl php7.3-gd php7.3-intl php7.3-json php7.3-mbstring php7.3-mysql php7.3-opcache php7.3-readline php7.3-xml php7.3-xsl php7.3-zip php7.3-bz2 libapache2-mod-php7.3 -y
apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client -y
clear
echo "Ok your done all has been setup."
echo "bye."
```

do not forget to make this file executable with `chmod +x install`